# How to port this C "Random generator" code to Java?

Tags: java, c, random

It's a pretty simple code, but I do not know what to do about the unsigned int, since java does not have unsigned int.  Is there a way to "simulate" an unsigned int in Java?

```
    uint32_t myrand() {
        static uint32_t next = 1;
        next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
        return next;
    }
```

How can I create a method in java that will return the same values? What to do about the unsigned int?

I coded a form to handle the summation problem, but the did not come up with a solution to the multiplication part.

The limit is the limit of the unsigned int (4294967295).

My algorithm basically whenever the summation is equal to 4294967296 it turns into 0 e starts all over again.

```
    public long add(long x, long y) {

        long result = 0L;

        if (x + y < this.limit) {

            if ((x + y) % this.limit == 0) {
                result = (x + y) / 2;
            } else {
                result = (x + y) % this.limit;
            }

        } else {

            if ((x + y) % this.limit == 0) {
                result = (x + y) / (Math.max(x, y) / Math.min(x, y)) - 1;
            } else {
                result = (x + y) % this.limit - 1;
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question and explain your algorithm. Tell us the purpose of the code, not what it does. I think it is way too complicated, and `(x + y ) % 0x100000000` should be sufficient. For the modulo operation you need 1 more than the maximum value of a `uint32_t`: `0x100000000` or `4294967296`. The same for the multiplication: `(x * y) % 0x100000000`, or combined `(next * 1103515245 + 12345) % 0x100000000`.

Comment: Or use bitwise and

Comment: Java can simulate an unsigned int by basically covering your eyes and ears and pretending the sign bit is just a normal bit. The mathematics will work out the same and can be displayed using `Integer#toUnsignedString`. Alternatively, you can just use a `long` if you're okay with a little extra memory cost.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to do much.  The way Java represents integers means that those operations will overflow to the same value as in C.  It's just that the return value would need to be converted to `long` in order not to get negative values out (i.e. due to its use of [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integers).

```
class RandC {
    private static int state = 1;

    public static long next() {
        state = state * 1103515245 + 12345;
        return state & 0xffffffffl;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(next());
        System.out.println(next());
        System.out.println(next());
    }
}
```

gives me:

```
1103527590
2524885223
662824084
```

which are the values I'd expect.